# How to interpret cost in case of K-Prototypes in kmodes, Python?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, evaluation

I'm doing a clustering on mixed (numerical and categorical) type data with [kmodes.kprototypes](https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes) in Python:

```
from kmodes.kprototypes import KPrototypes

kp = KPrototypes(n_clusters=5, init='Cao')
kp.fit(df, categorical=categorical_column_list)
```

After done, I would like to evaluate/compare the results. As I work with mixed type data, I cannot use any of [sklearn's usual clustering evaluation methods](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-performance-evaluation) (they're for numerical data only as I understood). Instead, KPrototypes provides built in `.cost_` attribute with some kind of aggregated similarities (it's [source code docstring](https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes/blob/7481a88841e67d99d47287ea7b8a36f4a14d5344/kmodes/kprototypes.py#L95) declares that it is "*defined as the sum distance of all points to their respective cluster centroids*").

I'm not sure how to interpret this cost. Based on my poor understanding of the code, it is indeed the summary of distance values for each data points, but this would mean that the higher `n_clusters` is, the lower `cost_` would be (and indeed, this is the tendency) and in extreme (but absurd) case of `n_clusters = len(X)` `cost_` would be the lowest.

What actually `cost_` is here, and could it be used for usual evaluation? If not, what metrics to use here?

Comment: The source docstring also refers to this [publication](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1009769707641). Does that help understand it?

Comment: The referred publication is accessible only with institutional subscription which I sadly lack.

Comment: Here is a copy: https://srv25.fileconverto.com/download.php?hash=a591b79ac2fab02b1cf3272c0d94d9a5

Comment: Thanks. The authors say: "In evaluating the k-modes and k-prototypes algorithms, we adopted an external criterion which measures the degree of correspondence between the clusters obtained from our clustering algorithms and the classes assigned a priori." Which means that no way to evaluate without pre-known classes if I understand well.

Comment: If you have a question about the algorithm I think it's better asked over at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://or.stackexchange.com/